# Convert One Dimensional Arrary to Two Dimensional in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, int, dimensional

I have a 49 space one dimensional array declared as `int boardArray [49];` and I also have a two dimensional 7x7 array declared as `int boardArrayTwo [7][7]'` I am trying to use nested for loops to throw the one dimensional array into the two dimensional array here is the code I am using to test it.

```
for (int i = 0; i > 50; ++i)
{
    boardArray[i] = i; //fills the array with ints 0 - 48 to test
}
for (int x = 0; x >= 7; ++x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k >= 7; ++k)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n >= 49; ++n)
        {
            boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[n];
            cout << boardArrayTwo[x][k] << " " << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

I tried running this but nothing happens. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The loops headed by for (int n = 0; n >= 49; ++n)
and for (int x = 0; x >= 7; ++x) are going to run exactly 0 times.  That's why nothing will happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int x = 0; x >= 7; ++x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k >= 7; ++k){
         for (int n = 0; n >= 49; ++n)
    {
```

this is wrong. x and k should be < 7 (and the third cycle shouldn't be used) :

```
for (int x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; ++k){
        boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[7*x + k];
```

EDIT:

like @Fabio Ceconello make me notice in his comment, even the first loop is wrong because of the inverted condition checks, it should be modified this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 49; ++i)
{
    boardArray[i] = i; //fills the array with ints 0 - 48 to test
}
```

Comment: Not only that, all the conditionals in the loops have inverted logic.

Comment: what's wrong? I'm not understanding the objections. could you both clarify to me?

Comment: You should include what was mentioned below by Fabio. That would make your answer the best I think.

Comment: oh.you are right. I completely forgot the first cycle. I'll edit my answer thanks

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the inverted logic in the loops (which the others mentioned), there's no need for the third inner loop. Just put the attribution in the second inner loop:

```
boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[x * 7 + k];
```

EDIT:
I should also mention that all these literals aren't good practice, and I added one more (7) above. I'd rewrite the code as follows:

```
#define arrlen(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))

for (int i = 0; i < arrlen(boardArray); ++i)
{
    boardArray[i] = i; 
}
int stride = arrlen(boardArrayTwo[0]);
for (int x = 0; x < arrlen(boardArrayTwo); ++x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < stride; ++k)
    {
        boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[stride * x + k];
        cout << boardArrayTwo[x][k] << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

caveat: if the arrays aren't declared here (were passed as parameters), arrlen() won't work. But that's another long story...

Comment: Hey but there is also the matter than 0 <= 7 gives him 8 values. That's too many for his tiny tiny arrays!

Comment: Right, he should use x < and k <, not x <= & etc.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your destination array is in row-major order. You could just blast the source array directly into place.

```
memcpy(boardArrayTwo, boardArray, 49 * sizeof(int));
```

or if you prefer something in more idiomatic C++:

```
std::copy(boardArray, boardArray + 49, reinterpret_cast<int*>(boardArrayTwo));
```

Comment: I hate casts. How about `std::copy(&boardArray[0], &boardArray[49], &boardArrayTwo[0][0]);`

Comment: @Rob, that works too. I don't mind the new C++ casts too much. They stand out in the code so you can find them and they give the compiler a chance to catch some misuse.

Answer (score 4):

You used `i > 50` in your for loop. It should be `i < 49` and same for all the other loops.

Also, this won't work. You're setting all of the `boardArrayTwo[][]` values to `boardArray[49]` You should instead do something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; ++k)
    {
        boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[7*x + k];
        cout << boardArrayTwo[x][k] << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

or

```
int count = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; ++k)
    {
        boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[count];
        cout << boardArrayTwo[x][k] << " " << endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the second term in the `for` loop says the for loop would run while that condition is true. So you should use `<` instead of `>=` for all your loops.

Second, the loop over `n` is extra and shouldn't be there. What you need is to go through `x` and `k`, then copy the corresponding element from `boardArray` to `boardArrayTwo`.

You could do one of these:

```
int n = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; ++k)
    {
        boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[n];
        ++n;
    }
```

or use a formula to calculate the proper `n`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; ++k)
        boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[x*7+k];
```

I wrote `x*7+k` because it seems like `x` is iterating over the rows of the array, each row having 7 elements, says that `x*7+k`th element of the boardArray represents position `[x][k]` of boardArrayTwo/

Answer (score 0):

Note

```
for (int i = 0; i > 50; ++i)
```

if `i` is initialized to 0, it won't be greater than `50` and thus it will never enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In each of your loops you used greater than or equal (>) to rather than less than (<) or equal to. You should also notice that, as Fabio points out above, the third nested loop is setting `boardArrayTwo[x][k]` to 0-49 over and over again, 49 times. You will need to use arithmetic to manipulate x and k so that they will be an index into boardArray, and then assign that index to `boardArrayTwo[x][k]`.

It's also important that you are using 0..7 inclusive, which is actually 8 positions. Your array are only of length 7 so you are actually ending up with some garbage values in there.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main () {

    int boardArray[49];
    int boardArrayTwo[7][7];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    boardArray[i] = i; //fills the array with ints 0 - 48 to test
}
for (int x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; ++k)
    {
            boardArrayTwo[x][k] = boardArray[x*7 + k];
            cout << boardArrayTwo[x][k] << " " << endl;
    }
}

}
```

With any luck (unless I am embarrassing myself) this should do the trick!

EDIT: Special thanks to Fabio!

Comment: It won't work fine. Even with reversed operators, he's still setting all of the `boardArrayTwo[x][k]` values to boardArray[49].

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<49; i++)
b[i]=(i+1);

int p=0;
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {a[i][j]=b[p];
        p++;}
        }
```

> beside other errors, third loop is making your code wrong