# Treat one-dimensional array as two-dimensional

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I have one-dimensional array

```
int* a = new int[n * m];
```

and i need to treat it as two-dimensional i.e

```
a[i][j] = a[n * i + j]
```

I have tried playing around using directives and googled a lot. But nothing worked for me.
Is there any way to do so? Smt. like `define a[i][j] a[n * i + j]` ?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you have search not much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492842/convert-one-dimensional-arrary-to-two-dimensional-in-c

Comment: Any `array_view`, or the GSL's `span` class, should be able to do this without changing anything about the array itself.

Comment: I assume you only have one allocation because you want the data to be contiguous?

Comment: @Joachim, yes. I just need substitution.

Comment: Can you please tell us *why* you want this "substitution"? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? What is the use-case? [Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're programming in C++ you could create a wrapper-class which holds the array, and have an `operator[]` function which returns a proxy object whose `operator[]` function performs the `n * i + j` calculation and returns a reference to the wanted element.

Alternatively you can create an inline function or function-like macro which takes the array and indexes as arguments and return the element.

But without hacks like the one in [Sams answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254129/440558) of wrapper classes, there is no way of getting a "true" array of arrays like you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a second array that contains pointers. Something like this:

```
int **b=new int *[m];

for (int i=0; i<m; ++i)
     b[i]=&a[i*n];
```

After that, `b[i][j]` will refer to `a[n*i+j]`.

Comment: While this is a possible solution, it does have some problems that a single "array" doesn't, mainly about locality and CPU caching.

Comment: I don't want to allocate array of pointers and then each allocate memory for each of the pointer. I just want substitution `a[i][j] = a[n * i + j]`

Comment: @T_Igor Note that the code in the answer doesn't actually do what you think it does. The loop doesn't allocate memory, just assignment.